# Java: Parse Date String with timezone abbreviations to Date object

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I need to parse a date string with timezone to `Date` object. The input date string pattern is:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a z"  (eg: 04/30/2018 06:00 PM IST).
```

I have used below given code. But it returns incorrect date as output.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a z").parse("04/30/2018 06:00 PM IST")
```

Current Output: `"Mon Apr 30 09:00:00 PDT 2018"`. 
Expected Output: `"Mon Apr 30 05:30:00 PDT 2018`.

Comment: What is your current output and what are you expecting?

Comment: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a z" should be used instead of "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a z". H — Hour in day (0-23). h — Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Comment: @MikitaHerasiutsin: Thanks. I used hh only. It was a typo error.

Comment: @NisheethShah: Current Output: "Mon Apr 30 09:00:00 PDT 2018"
Expected Output: "Mon Apr 30 05:30:00 PDT 2018"

Comment: @Salman Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than Comments. Your readers should not have to comb through Comments to understand your Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because [timezone's abbreviations such as **IST** are ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231). **IST** is used in [India, Israel and Ireland](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/#anc-9), and `SimpleDateFormat` assumes some of them as default, in obscure and undocumented ways (AFAIK). Actually, [according to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)): *"support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility only and full names should be used"*.

One way to make it work is to arbitrarily choose a timezone and set it in the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
Date date = sdf.parse("04/30/2018 06:00 PM IST");
```

Always use names in the format **Continent/Region**, such as `Asia/Kolkata`. Those names are [IANA's timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), and they are not ambiguous, so this make things work.

### java.time API

If you're using Java 8 or higher, switch to the [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), which is much better. For Java 7 or lower, there's the [Threeten Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) with the same classes and functionality.

In this API, you must set a list of all preferred timezones to be used in case of ambiguous names like **IST**:

```
// prefered zones
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<>();
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time
    .appendPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a ")
    // zone (use set of prefered zones)
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // use English, because different locales can affect timezones names
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("04/30/2018 06:00 PM IST", fmt);
```

If you still need to use `java.util.Date`, it's easy to convert:

```
// Java 8
Date d = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());

// Java 7 (Threenten Backport)
Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate(zdt.toInstant());
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have implemented your first approach and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The resultant Date object will not hold any timezone information. See the similar query in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271681/simpledateformat-ignores-timezone)

You might be getting the correct date but in your JVM's current timezone.

In case if you are using Java 8, then there's a provision of Date object with timezone. Look at [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), but for this you need a different kind of formatter while parsing ([DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html))